# Buscar dato en base de datos en SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle-sqldeveloper

tengo un problema en sql, tengo una base de datos en donde tengo 3 tablas: EMPLEADO, PRESTAMO y CTAAHORRO, y necesito sacar el nombre de empleado (NOMBREEMP) que se encuentra en las 3 tablas usando el identificador del empleado, alguien podría decirme cómo porfavor

Comment: Te recomiendo colocar tu sql, tus tablas, lo que haz intentado para que te podamos ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entendí tendrías que introducir el siguiente código:

```
SELECT e.NOMBREEMP
from EMPLEADO e, PRESTAMO p, CTAAHORRO c
where p.NUMEMP=e.NUMEMP and c.NUMEMP=e.NUMEMP
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Díana, me ayudaste mucho eres lo que necesitaba :3